# Request Time out of mLab with Heroku

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I'm here because I've a problem using MongoDB and mLab.

I know it's a common problem of "Request Time Out", but I don't understand the solution using socket and the others does'nt work.

Could someone help me with this problem ? Here are the info of my code, even if it's basic.

```
const db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://<user>: 
<mdp>@ds223009.mlab.com:23009/arnaudscieur", function( err, response){
if(err){console.log(err);}
});
```

Of course, user and mdp are replaced by my info, and they are correct.

Here are the error

```
2018-10-10T13:06:08.507298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 
desc="Request timeout"
method=GET path= "/GetArticle?Number=0" host=arsc.herokuapp.com 
request_id=c69ed184-e646-4c09-ac03-cfc2b1aca41a fwd="193.190.255.225" 
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Thank you in advance ! :)